# Is AWS Aurora Multi-Master cluster suitable for WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, woocommerce, amazon-aurora

I have a situation where during peak moments my writer database even on the largest 96 core AWS instance becomes maxed (due to limited edition promotions where we process hundreds of orders per second).

I have seen that Aurora offer a multi-master setup where all nodes of the cluster are able to write - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-multi-master.html

In the docs they mention:

> If two DB instances attempt to modify the same data page at almost the same instant, a write conflict occurs. The earliest change request is approved using a quorum voting mechanism. That change is saved to permanent storage. The DB instance whose change isn't approved rolls back the entire transaction containing the attempted change. Rolling back the transaction ensures that data is kept in a consistent state, and applications always see a predictable view of the data. Your application can detect the deadlock condition and retry the entire transaction.

I am not really sure what they mean here by "data page".  I am pretty sure WordPress doesn't use transactions at all but when thousands of orders are coming in and being pushed into the same table will this cause write errors that will cause orders to fail?

I have looked online and cannot find anyone talking about using WordPress with Aurora multi-master cluster.  Is it compatible?

Comment: I would recommend asking this in the dedicated [WordPress StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com). But in the short core WP would be fine with it.